# drupal_static and XHProf

Tags: 6, debugging

I'm using D6 but stole drupal_static() from D7 for a high demand site I'm currently working on.

I'm currently optimising some of the slower pages with XHProf which has been fine, but I'm getting a strange result with drupal_static().

It doesn't matter whether I use:

```
$registry = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
```

Or the fast static method:

```
static $registry;
if (!isset($registry)) {
  $registry = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
}
```

The number of calls to `drupal_static()` is given as the same in XHProf.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where are you using those snippets?

Comment: In a function that gets called a lot. (And the registry is required elsewhere as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either `static` declaration or `drupal_static()`, but not both for the same variable. The issue here is that the reference is lost because [references are not stored statically](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references).

From https://www.drupal.org/node/619666#comment-2211696

> So unfortunately this is not possible (declarations of static variables don't accept expressions):

```
static $implementations = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
```

> An this neither ([it'll lose the reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references)):

```
static $implementations;
if (!isset($implementations)) {
  $implementations = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
}
```

> But this is:

```
static $cache = array();
if (!isset($cache['implementations'])) {
  $cache['implementations'] = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
} 
$implementations = &$cache['implementations'];
```

So you should do this:

```
static $cache;
if (!isset($cache)) {
  $cache['registry'] = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());
}
$registry = &$cache['registry'];
```

Comment: The second example is Drupal's fast static pattern, it's used in functions that get called a lot. There's info about it on the [docs page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7)

Comment: I see. But that is creating 2 static variables, isn't it?

Comment: Also, note that in the example you link, the same variable is not used with `static` and `drupal_static()`. Is using `static` in an array and `drupal_static()` in an element of that array.

Comment: No, it isn't. Is reusing a static $data variable inside `drupal_static()` and creating a $registry static variable in your function. No idea, there's more info in https://www.drupal.org/node/619666 too

Comment: Actually I deleted my comment before I saw your reply - so your reply to my (deleted) reply doesn't entirely make sense now. Sorry. I'm willing to be wrong :-) just testing...

Comment: The purpose of the fast static pattern is to avoid the overheads of the function call and array lookup in `drupal_static()` - that is, you have a locally cached reference to the data without having to call `drupal_static()` each time, but the cache can still be 'managed' (cleared/queried) through `drupal_static()`. If you have a function being called potentially thousands of times in a single request, these small cost-savings start to add up

Comment: Bingo! Sorry for doubting you :-)

Number of calls gone from 2000 to 1.

Comment: No worries my answer was originally wrong anyway :)